# Why is Android Studio trying to locate resource in debug package instead of the main one?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle

I have an app with 4 different build types: debug and release (the normal ones), as well as alpha and beta. I declare the types in build.gradle as follows:

```
buildTypes {
    // The release (or "live") variant. Application id is app.myapp.live
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        debuggable false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        applicationIdSuffix ".live"

        ext.enableCrashlytics = true

        // Build config fields
        buildConfigField("boolean", "RELEASE", "true")
    }

    // The debug variant. Application id is app.myapp.debug
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        debuggable true

        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'

        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }

    // The alpha variant. Application id is app.myapp.alpha
    alpha {
        initWith release
        debuggable true

        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
        versionNameSuffix '-ALPHA'
    }

    // The beta variant. Closer to live. Application id is app.myapp.beta
    beta {
        initWith release
        debuggable true

        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
    }
}
```

My folder structure is correct and the only thing I override in the different build variants is strings.xml (where the app name differs). This all works correctly.

Now, when having debug selected as build variant, and I try to reference resources in a layout file, I get the following from AS:

> Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'arc1Color' in package 'app.myapp.debug'

Why is it looking in "app.myapp.debug"? Java packages should stay the same, only the package id (and application id) should be different in the merged manifest when building. Or is my thinking wrong here?

I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' and running AS 2.3.1

Comment: Sigh, so after spending quite a lot of time on this I realized there was a problem with my layouts. I'm using Data Binding and Realm together, and it's still a learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the java package with the package name and the application Id.

> When you create a new project in Android Studio, the applicationId exactly matches the Java-style package name you chose during setup. However, the application ID and package name are independent of each other beyond this point. You can change your code's package name (your code namespace) and it will not affect the application ID, and vice versa

And:

> Although you may have a different name for the manifest package and the Gradle applicationId, the build tools copy the application ID into your APK's final manifest file at the end of the build. So if you inspect your AndroidManifest.xml file after a build, don't be surprised that the package attribute has changed

More [details here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

Since you are using:

```
debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
```

Your package becomes `'app.myapp.debug'` but the java package of your classes doesn't change.

> Error:(16) No resource identifier found for attribute 'arc1Color'

It means that in the **debug build type** you are not defining the attribute `arc1Color` (may be it is defined in the resources inside other build types). Check your resources files.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gabriele! I found my problem (it was unrelated to the packages).